# Set containing folder as variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to get put my containing folder as a set of variable in my batch file. For example i Have

c:\Monday\AM

Monday will be save to variable A while AM will be save to variable B

How can I achieve that?

Once I know that I will create an if else statement base on the name saved on the variable (e.g Monday\AM = 1\2 Tuesday\AM = 2\2 Monday\PM = 1\1)

hope this better explain my question

Comment: it looks like you're asking for somthing you think you need, but probably don't. Try to explain the task, and provide your code so far.

Comment: A folder and B folder is always changing and there is a corresponding number base on the folder name (eg sample\folder = 1\2 sample2\folder = 2\2) Thats why i want to save those two folders name in a variable to create an if else (not loop sorry) . Honestly I dont have any code for this as I only know very basic in batch file/script?

Comment: How does the batch file know what folder structure to use if you do not already know it?

Comment: Please update your post with the real folder path and names an explain what you mean by corresponding base number on the folder name. _Adding information to the comments are either not seen or too difficult to read_.

Comment: @Squashman Im thinking like batch file is already on the folder path(sample C:\Monday\AM)batch then gets the whole directory path as variable, then seperate them via \ so i can get their folders name to seperate variable (A=Monday B=AM)

Comment: You need to explain a little better what the intended purpose of this script is.  What if the batch file is nested 5, 6 or even 10 folders deep?

Comment: ok so normally i have to manually edit a batch code i use  when I place that particular batch file in a different folder.(eg batch file is in C:\Monday\AM and put it on C:\Monday\PM .  i have to edit those line that has C:\Monday\AM to C:\Monday\PM)

What I am trying to achieve is instead of editing I save the path as a variable, seperate 1st and 2nd folder to A and B then make an if else statement (like if A=Monday and B=AM echo 1/2 or if A=Monday and B=PM echo 2/2)

Comment: Please put all information directly related to the question into your post by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40241897/edit) rather than spreading it over multiple comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get the directory the batch file resides in (child) and the folder above that (parent).

```
@echo off
for %%G in ("%~dp0\.") do set child=%%~nxG
for %%G in ("%~dp0\..") do set parent=%%~nxG
echo child=%child%
echo parent=%parent%
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure, this is a [x-y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) (therefore the request "Try to explain the task"). But if you insist in doing it that way:

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
for %%X in (%cd%) do set _b=%%~nxX
pushd ..
for %%X in (%cd%) do set _a=%%~nxX
popd
popd
echo %_a%, %_b%
```

This switches into the folder where your batch-file resides (that's `%~dp0`) and gets the last two elements into variables. When finished, it restores to the original working folder.